# How to write custom rule to prevent some method call in SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

Suppose i have one **class A** and it has three method **met1,met2** and **met3** i want to build a custom rule where if someone calls **met3** it should throw some custom message showing as non compliant solution in sonar?

Answer (score 2):

[At the official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/) you can found following:

> **Adding Coding Rules**
>
> There are three ways to add coding rules to SonarQube:
>
> - Writing a SonarQube plugin in Java that uses SonarQube APIs to add    new rules
> - Adding XPath rules directly through the SonarQube web    interface
> - Importing Generic Issue Reports generated by an    independently run tool

My advice is to create plugin:

> Writing coding rules in Java is a six-step process:
>
> 1. Create a SonarQube plugin.
> 2. Put a dependency on the API of the language plugin for which you are writing coding rules.
> 3. Create as many custom rules as required.
> 4. Generate the SonarQube plugin (jar file).
> 5. Place this jar file in the SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins
>    directory.
> 6. Restart SonarQube server.

[Here is a book for Sonarqube](https://livebook.manning.com/book/sonarqube-in-action/chapter-16/) with a chapter for creating custom plugins and [here is a GitHub project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example/blob/9.x/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/plugins/example/rules/JavaRulesDefinition.java) with an example.